# Why doesn't calling repr on type objects work as expected?

Tags: python-3.x

First, let me say that I agree that `eval(repr(some_string))` is potentially a bad idea. But it is a thing that exists, and I have a specific question about it.

Why doesn't this work?

```
my_type = int 
my_type_str = repr(int)  
my_type_from_str = eval(my_type_str)
```

To clarify, I know specifically why the `eval` call fails. The command `repr(int)` produces a string which cannot be automatically interpreted. I guess my issue is that this isn't behaving as *I* expect... so either my expectation is faulty *or* the implementation is faulty. Which is it?

### Side Note

There are some tricks that can be used to get around this default behavior, some obvious, some not. For instance, this:

```
my_type = int 
my_type_str = my_type.__name__
my_type_from_str = eval(my_type_str)
assert my_type is my_type_from_str
```

This sets off my "hack" alert hardcore, and I don't like it (or other similar hacks, for instance parsing the string `"<class 'int'>"` with some home made function).

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) explains:

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. **For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`**, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a **repr**() method.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So, it doesn't say that `repr` must *always* return valid Python code - sometimes it's not the case. Just another argument for not relying on it.